spring webflux unable to connect elastic search after some days untill pod restart
we have developed spring webflux API which fetch response from elastic search, API giving timeout after few days of deployment, request is getting cancelled while retrieving data from elastic search and getting the error "message":"elastic search data processing completed with signal: cancel", And API is working fine after pod restart.
backend elastic search : 8.7.1
Attaching pom dependencies:
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.12.1</version>
        </dependency>

Also tried with springboot version :3.1.0 and co.elastic.clients : 8.7.1


**Adding Impl for invoking elastic search :**


    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchAsyncClient elasticsearchAsyncClient;

    @Autowired
    private ElasticSearchRequestBuilder elasticSearchRequestBuilder;

    private CompletableFuture<SearchResponse<Output>> getAsyncSearchResponse(IntermediateRequestObject intermediateObject, RequestDTO requestDTO) {
    SearchRequest searchRequest = elasticSearchRequestBuilder.getSearchRequest(intermediateObject,
                requestDTO);
        return elasticsearchAsyncClient.search(searchRequest, Output.class);

}


